# how to make a two time input which one of them is always greater than the other with one hour

Tags: html, time, datepicker

i want to make the endH change once i enter startH to become 1 hour greater

```
<input type="time" id="startH">
<input type="time" id="endH">
```

i used datepicker on date but i'm lost on how to resolve the hour problem

 exemple : 
startH 16:00 endH 17:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript, first get the value of StartH.

you can do something like:

```
var startHStr = document.getElementById("startH").value;
```

it will return a string like "08:30" (read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Time_value_format))

Than, write some code to make it a string for one hour later "09:30".

Assign this new string to endH Dom Object

```
document.getElementById("startH").value = endHStr; // endHString = "09:30"
```

You may want to write this code in onchange event handler function of startH object like this:

```
document.getElementById("startH").onchange = function (){
    // your logic
}
```

Comment: my problem was on how to make it 1 hour greater not the onchange function , i've been told that js doesn't have a good time api and this may be impossible to do!

Comment: well, string is in format of hh:mm. parse the string, increment the hh part than form a new string and assign it to the endh. It's definitly possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<p>Click the button to parse different strings.</p>
<input type="time" value="00:00" id="startH" > 
<input  type="time" id="endH">
<button >Try it</button>
</form>


<script>


function hmsToSecondsOnly(str) {
    var p = str.split(':'),
        s = 0, m = 1;

    while (p.length > 0) {
        s += m * parseInt(p.pop(), 10);
        m *= 60;
    }
String.prototype.toHHMMSS = function () {
    var sec_num = parseInt(this, 10);
    var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours   < 10) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
}

    return s;
}
document.getElementById("startH").onchange = function (){
  var starthstr = 60*hmsToSecondsOnly(document.getElementById("startH").value);
  starthstr = starthstr.toString().toHHMMSS()
  starthstr = hmsToSecondsOnly(f);
  starthstr = starthstr + 1*(60*60);
  var endHstr = starthstr.toString().toHHMMSS();
  document.getElementById("endH").min=endHstr;
  document.getElementById("endH").value =endHstr;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this was my solution with the help of some stackoverflow codes and ty t.m. for helping me